# why auto conversions between Java and Scala collections fail?

Tags: java, scala

I have two Java classes: `LogEntry` and `Record`.

The `LogEntry` class has a method shown below:

```
public LogEntry setRec(List<Map<String,List<Record>>> rec)
```

In Scala I try to put `Record` into `LogEntry` like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.mutable._
val log = new LogEntry()
val rec = new Record()

val map:java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[Record]] = HashMap("sessionKey" -> ArrayBuffer(rec))
log.setRec(List(map))
```

But I got a compile error:

```
scala> val map:java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[Record]] = HashMap("sessionKey" -> ArrayBuffer(eventPart))
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Record]]
 required: java.util.Map[String,java.util.List[Record]]
       val map:java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[Record]] = HashMap("sessionKey" -> ArrayBuffer(eventPart))
                                                                      ^
```

Seems that the auto convention from Scala collection to Java collection failed, but as described in [the official doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_46.html) :

```
mutable.Buffer   <=>     java.util.List   
mutable.Map     <=>     java.util.Map

scala> val jul: java.util.List[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)   
jul: java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3]   

scala> val m: java.util.Map[String, Int] = HashMap("abc" -> 1, "hello" -> 2)   
m: java.util.Map[String,Int] = {hello=2, abc=1}
```

`ArrayBuffer` can be convert to `java.util.List` and `HashMap` can be convert to `java.util.Map`.

So, why this error occurred?

Comment: @sschaef thanks for your patient edit, I will pay more attention to the format and grammar in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit conversions don't apply to type parameters (though you can use view bounds to simulate it). That is, if you have implicit conversion from `Foo` to `Bar`, values of type `Foo` can be used where `Bar` is needed:

```
val foo: Foo = ...
def bar(b: Bar) = ...
bar(foo)
```

but (e.g.) `Seq[Foo]` can't be used instead of `Seq[Bar]`:

```
val foo: Foo = ...
def bar(list: Seq[Bar]) = ...
bar(Seq(foo)) // type error
```

That's why conversion between `ArrayBuffer` and `java.util.List` can't be used there.

Comment: Thanks, your answer explained why it doesn't work,and now it doesn't seems to be as weird as it was.

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to some quirk in scala implicit conversions. The following should work.

```
val map: java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[EventPart]] = 
  HashMap("sessionKey" -> (ArrayBuffer(eventPart):java.util.List[EventPart]))
```

As a test I did

```
scala>  val map:java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[String]] = 
   HashMap("sessionKey" -> (ArrayBuffer("aa"):java.util.List[String]))
map: java.util.Map[String,java.util.List[String]] = {sessionKey=[aa]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of scala you are using, but in the latest [the official doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) , your have to firstly import collection.JavaConverters._ and then calling asJava or asScala to convert collection objects between original java and scala.
See the official example as below:

```
scala> import collection.mutable._
import collection.mutable._

scala> val jul: java.util.List[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3).asJava

jul: java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3]

scala> val buf: Seq[Int] = jul.asScala

buf: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)

scala> val m: java.util.Map[String, Int] = HashMap("abc" -> 1, "hello" -> 2).asJava

m: java.util.Map[String,Int] = {abc=1, hello=2}
```